# Error with chalk module installing Vue-cli

Tags: npm, vuejs2, chalk

Configuring VUE-CLI I am having the next problem:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
>       throw err;
>       ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/vue:3:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

I have tried to install the module globally but with the same result, when I type in the terminal `vue`error appears again.

Could you tell me please how to fix this problem?

Comment: if you are using hosting platforms like heroku you need to build your app before uploading it to the server

Comment: No, at the moment this problem is in local installation..

Comment: them make sure it's built

Comment: As far I know, it is needed to instance vue command to create a new app skeleton, if I cannot use that instruction I cannot to build it.. 

Comment: yeah, but sometimes it works if you build. I got that library issue many times you can see here someone also got it and solved it the same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611909/some-troubles-with-deploying-vue-js-to-heroku#comment88234249_50611909

Comment: with vue-build??   it is not working for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed adding the correct PATHS in the .zshrc file, I was adding them to the bash_profile but I am working with other shell.

Answer (score -1):

see the error "Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'"
try
npm install chalk